# Grid layout last rows being cut off

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a layout which holds the grid layout as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_gallery_mine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="4dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/empty_list" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that, the last rows of the grid is being cut to half. I mean the last row is only half visible. I tried giving the gridview and also its parent (RelativeLayout) padding, margin but nothing works. BTW I have this layout inflated inside a fragment with the tabs.

P.S I am learning android design. Thanks.

Comment: Please add screenshot to see issue and layout `xml` of grid item.

Comment: You have a gridVIEW not a gridLayout

Answer (score 0):

I had used the combinations of

1. Android basic actionbar,
2. tabhost from support library.

The answer to above question was since i had no other options for implementation, Applying padding bottom on the parent node of the content made it work.

I tried another combination with the **Toolbar in appcompat v7.21** (or 21), **It worked** without the extra padding, So i dint get time to investigate who causing the problem, actionbar or tabhost.

~ Hope it helps